# Integrating Zoom with default Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, big-sur, zoom.app

I have `Calendar` events with `Zoom` links in them. Is there a way so that when I click on the link, Zoom desktop client is used to open them instead of my default web-browser?

I am using MBA M1 with macOS Big Sur 11.2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for motivating me to actually share the Automator service I made for this!

https://jonathanalland.com/quick-actions.html

Install the Open In Zoom service, then highlight a Zoom URL, right click, and select "Open in Zoom". This has only been tested on OS X 10.9, but I see no reason it shouldn't work on modern macOS as well.

I created this by looking at the `zoommtg://` protocol format, and then doing some find/replace magic in shell and Applescript. (I ideally should have used just one, but doing it in two steps was a tad easier, because shell is more powerful but I'm more comfortable in Applescript.)

Comment: Ah, a website with an well-written privacy policy :-)

Comment: Works perfectly. Is there a way to have the "Open in Zoom" option in `right_click` menu or the `right_click-->Open With` menu rather than `right-click-->Services` menu? This is the kind of feature that should come bundled with the "most advanced" operating system in the world -_-.

Comment: @asymptoticallyboundedgluon Yes, disable some services, you have too many! `System Preferences` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts` → `Services`. (Specifically, you need to disable whichever other ones appear when you highlight a URL and right click).